# Android studio Flamingo gradle.properties shows garbled characters in Chinese

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android studio gradle.properties shows garbled characters in Chinese, which appeared after updating `flamingo`.

This is my Android studio version：

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
```

The Encoding under my settings `-Editor -File Encodings` is normal `UTF-8`, and I also added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` under `studio64.exe.vmoptions`, and added org.gradle under `gradle.properties. jvmargs= -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart with administrator

Comment: "try invalidate cache and restart with administrator" I tried but it doesn't work